# Which MySQL collation compares e.g. é and e as equal?

Tags: mysql, collation

EDIT: if no such collation exists, I can work around it if MySQL has a function which will convert strings into ASCII equivalents e.g. `FUNC('Være')='Vaere'` -- there might be several such functions, one for each alphabet, which would be a hassle but acceptable if effective.

---

I need a MySQL5 collation which will compare accented characters as equivalent, irrespective of accents. e.g. "fêter" should be considered equal to "feter" and "eł" should match "el"

Ideally this wouldn't be limited to single-character substitutions, e.g. "For At Være Som Man Bør" should be considered equal to "For At Vaere Som Man Bor". `WHERE name LIKE '%ere%'` should also match it.

I see there are collations for spanish/polish/etc, but I need **one** collation to cover **all** latin-like alphabets (not Arabic or Asian ones etc). The strings are stored as UTF-8.

Which collation should I use?

Comment: What about case sensitivity, is it okay if it's not case sensitive in comparison?

Comment: Case insensitive, at least for now. Ideally I could choose this at runtime.

Comment: I can't put together an answer right now (it's a slightly complicated topic and I forget the quirks and caveats every time)  but for anybody willing to dig, the answer is in here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you're using the utf8 characters set, the answer to your original question is "all of them except utf8_bin".

In all of these collations you will find that 'e' = 'ê'.

However, I don't know of any collations where 'æ' = 'ae' or 'ø' = 'o'.

```
 utf8_czech_ci
 utf8_danish_ci
 utf8_esperanto_ci
 utf8_estonian_ci
 utf8_general_ci
 utf8_hungarian_ci
 utf8_icelandic_ci
 utf8_latvian_ci
 utf8_lithuanian_ci
 utf8_persian_ci
 utf8_polish_ci
 utf8_roman_ci
 utf8_romanian_ci
 utf8_sinhala_ci
 utf8_slovak_ci
 utf8_slovenian_ci
 utf8_spanish_ci
 utf8_spanish2_ci
 utf8_swedish_ci
 utf8_turkish_ci
 utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

utf8-general-ci would be the closest one: http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html

Also note that as of MySQL 5.0 you can create your own collations. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-collation.html
http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/How_to_Add_a_Collation